# How can I run a cron job only when my laptop is active [WSL]?

Tags: cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux, powercfg

I have a small script (on WSL / Debian) to `rsync` my files to my Debian server.
I've set the script to run every two hours.

My laptop is a Windows 10 machine.

When put to sleep / idle, the laptop goes into a [Modern Standby](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby) state:

> When Modern Standby-capable systems enter sleep, the system is still
> in S0 (a fully running state, ready and able to do work).

This is [different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/modern-standby-vs-s3) from the old S3 state which is where the machine truly was on idle:

> Windows and the SoC hardware are always listening for interesting
> events (such as a network packet or user input at a keyboard) and will
> wake up instantly when needed. The system will wake when there is real
> time action required, such as for OS maintenance or when a user wakes
> the system

This means that even when I put my laptop to sleep, it's still running the `cron` job every two hours, which is unnecessary.

Is there any way that WSL can retrieve the power state, e.g. through `powercfg` so that it only runs the script when the computer is awake?

Comment: There doesn't seem to a be anything in the winapi docs under [power management functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/power-management-functions) that lets you see if you're in s0-low-power vs s0. There might not be a way to do this.